# WordPress wp_title blank on index page

Tags: wordpress, title

I'm new to WordPress and just installed version 3.3.1.

I did some googling regarding this question and found some answers but they were relevant to version 2.7 and were 2-3 years old.

Basically, the `wp_title` function works fine on every page except my home page where it returns blank and I get no title whatsoever. I could just hard code the title in but I'd rather not do that.

Guilty line of code:

```
<title><?php wp_title ( '| So Fresh n\' So Clean', true,'right' ); ?></title>
```

I couldn't find anything regarding this problem happening in 3.3.1 so clearly I've done something wrong.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Here's is what I read from [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title#Covering_Homepage):

> If you are using a custom homepage with custom loops and stuff, you
>   will have an empty `wp_title`. Here goes a neat hack to add the
>   description/tagline at the `wp_title` place on homepage:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

So use `is_front_page()` to get the title on homepage, the way it is suggested in above code.

Comment: prefer using is_front_page instead of is_home

Comment: is_front_page is preferred as it will be more versatile

Comment: This has now changed, the link is still valid but your answer is outdated

Comment: See waLL e's answer for a better solution on newer WP versions (>= 4.4) https://stackoverflow.com/a/37223205/1534704

Answer (score 14):

But if you use a static home page, this is the code:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> &raquo; <?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

Answer (score 13):

**Update**
for WordPress versions (>= 4.4)

Try this

```
function some_name(){
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'some_name' );
```

Do this in functions.php and remove 'title' tag from head...

Comment: This seems to be the more correct answer for newer versions of WP. I deleted the <title> tag from a template and the title tag appeared on the homepage.

Comment: It was stated as deprecated in 4.4. However is has been "Un-deprecate", https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/35624

Comment: Great solution, this also works way better with plugins like Yoast SEO that set the title.

Comment: For me, there is exactly such code in `functions.php`, and yet the main page has empty <title>.

Answer (score 9):

Working off of Amna's answer, I came up with the following code which should display the page title when there is one, followed by the site name.

```
<?php wp_title(' - ',TRUE,'right'); bloginfo('name'); ?>
```

Post/Page Outputs: "The Page Title - Site Name"

Home Page Outputs: "Site Name"

---

Obviously, this can also be swapped to display the site name first.

```
<?php bloginfo('name'); wp_title(' - '); ?>
```

Post/Page Outputs: "Site Name - The Page Title"

Home Page Outputs: "Site Name"

---

This can also be combined with a conditional to display the site description when viewing the home page.

```
<?php bloginfo('name'); echo ' - '; is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?>
```

Post/Page Outputs: "Site Name - The Page Title"

Home Page Outputs: "Site Name - The Site Description"

Comment: Your answer is perfect

Answer (score 4):

For google search on wordpress wp_title empty this is the first result. So I thought that I might share the most elegant solution for this.
In functions.php add a filter for wp_title.

```
function custom_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    if ( is_feed() ) {
        return $title;
    }

    global $page, $paged;

    // Add the blog name
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) {
        $title .= " $sep $site_description";
    }

    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) && ! is_404() ) {
        $title .= " $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', '_s' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'custom_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

The new hack from Codex is as follows:

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

Then in your "functions.php" from theme file :

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'baw_hack_wp_title_for_home' );
function baw_hack_wp_title_for_home( $title )
{
  if( empty( $title ) && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) {
    return __( 'Home', 'theme_domain' ) . ' | ' . get_bloginfo( 'description' );
  }
  return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this one and it never failed:

```
    function pageTitle($echo){
        $title = "";

        global $paged;
        if (function_exists('is_tag') && is_tag()) {        
            $title .= single_tag_title(__("Tag Archive for &quot;" , 'circle'),false); 
            $title .= '&quot; - '; 
        }
        elseif (is_archive()) {
            $title .= wp_title('',true); 
            //$title .= __(' Archive - ' , 'circle');
            $title .= __(' - ' , 'circle');

        }
        elseif (is_search()) {
        $title .= __('Search for &quot;' , 'circle') . esc_html(get_search_query()).'&quot; - '; 
        }
        elseif (!(is_404()) && (is_single()) || (is_page())) {
            $title .= wp_title('',true); 
            $title .= ' - '; 
        }
        elseif (is_404()) {
            $title .= __('Not Found - ' , 'circle'); 
        }
        if (is_home()) {
            $title .= get_bloginfo('name'); 
            $title .= ' - '; 
            $title .= get_bloginfo('description'); 
        }
        else {
            $title .= get_bloginfo('name'); 
        }
        if ($paged>1) {
            $title .= ' - page ' . $paged; 
        }

        if ( !$echo ) return $title;
        echo $title;
    }
```

**Note that there are translation domains in it that you might want to change.**

Comment: Obviously this is an more appropriate and useful code for child themes than the accepted answers. Just place it in the functions.php of your child theme.

Comment: Surprised no one's pointed out an obvious error if you try this code - wp_title('',true) should be wp_title('',$echo). Otherwise, if $echo is false then the title will be printed in the dom wherever it's called and it won't appear in the title tag.

Answer (score 1):

no need. Just add the `<? Php wp_head ();?>` Code at the end of the **header.php**

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method in my WordPress site

```
//Meta Header
if ( ! function_exists( 'dima_wp_title' ) ) :
  function dima_wp_title( $title ) {

    if ( is_front_page() ) {
      return get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . ' | ' . get_bloginfo( 'description' );
    } elseif ( is_feed() ) {
      return ' | RSS Feed';
    } else {
      return trim( $title ) . ' | ' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ); 
    }

  }
  add_filter( 'wp_title', 'dima_wp_title' );
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the conversation...

But if you want to use the actual title of the page that you are using for the static front page, you can use the following:

```
if (is_front_page())
{
    $title = single_post_title( '', false );
}
```

Although, in the actual source for wp_title(), there is the following, specificaly disabling this for the static front page:

```
if ( is_single() || ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) || ( is_page() && ! is_front_page() ) ) {
    $title = single_post_title( '', false );
}
```

I suspect there is good reason for this.  So, proceed with caution.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents for "misty lake" theme which had no title on home page and added incorrect title on all other pages.

Just removing the following line from header.php solves the issue, since Wordpress now injects the tag by itself:

```
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

I consulted the following page – https://make.wordpress.org/themes/2015/08/25/title-tag-support-now-required/

Answer (score 0):

You could also put something like this inside your title tag:

```
<?php 
    if (is_front_page()) { ?> 
        Home | <?php bloginfo('description'); 
    } else {
        wp_title('|', 'true', 'right'); bloginfo('description');
    } ?>
```