# WordPress wp_title bloginfo on one webserver missing

Tags: php, wordpress

Today I created for our website a staging environment to test new functionality.

Therefore I backed up the current homepage with UpdraftPlus and migrated this to the staging web server.

Everything is fine and the websites are almost identical.The only thing that is not equal, is the title.

I use this title statement `<title><?php wp_title('-', true, 'right'); ?></title>`.

On the origin website I get (how it should be):
On a sub page: `Sitename - Blogname`
On the home page: `Blogname`

The migrated:
On a subpage: `Sitename -`
On the home page:  blank

Both systems are running on the same WordPress version 4.9.4 (latest) and PHP 7.0

**Current research:**
When I use `<?php wp_title('-'); ?>` I get `- Sitename`

I do know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055009/wordpress-wp-title-blank-on-index-page) question, but this is only a workaround.

Comment: Take a look at: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/10/29/title-tags-in-4-1/ - wp_title() will be depricated in the future.

Comment: @RubenPauwels I'm aware of this. But they revoke this, see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/35624

Comment: @RubenPauwels And why should it still work on the production machine?

Comment: go to settings -> general and check Site Title and Tagline. it may be just a some bug with migration plugin, which didn't saved that parts

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan The right title is set

Comment: are both systems pointing to the same database?

Comment: @BenDubuisson No on two different.

Comment: Looks like one of the db doesn’t have its title set?

Comment: @BenDubuisson when I check this via phpMyAdmin the blogname is the same like the origin db.

Comment: Can you change db settings on one that doesn’t show it to the other db just to double check? Seems strange...

Comment: @BenDubuisson after some more research I get the feeling, that the behavior on the origin website is not right. I checked the internet for some tutorials and everyone is telling, that this command which I use usually doesn't return the value which it does in my case. Is there a possibility to change the behavior of this function?

Comment: Are both systems running on linux ?

Comment: @aidinMC yeah. Both are on the same host.

Comment: @daniel-eisenreich Why are you not using Yoast SEO? It'll be more helpful and easy more info: https://kb.yoast.com/kb/yoast-wordpress-seo-titles-metas-template-variables/

Comment: Maybe... you need to flush the options on the migrated site. I mean, visit `/wp-admin/options.php` (e.g. *http://example.com/wp-admin/options.php*) and click on the "*Save Changes*" button with or without actually making any changes.

Comment: @Sally no changes..