# wp_title('') return empty value if it is home/front page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, templates

I'm working with WordPress and using custom templates, I have use wp_title('') in the title tag
i.e

For all other pages, it is giving page name in the right way for all other pages except the home page, if it is the home page it is giving empty value.

I have tried the following codes:-

**Try 1:-**

```
<title><?php is_front_page() ? "Home" : wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

**Try 2:-**

```
<title><?php is_home() ? "Home" : wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

**Try 3:-**

```
<title><?php is_front_page() && is_home() ? "Home" : wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

**Try 4:-**

```
<title><?php is_front_page() || is_home() ? "Home" : wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

These pieces of code didn't work for me, Then I achieve my goal with the help of JQuery.

**JQuery code:-**

```
$(document).ready( () =>{
  domainHttps = "https://"+document.location.hostname+"/";
    domainHttp = "http://"+document.location.hostname+"/";
    url  = window.location.href;

    if(domainHttps == url || domainHttp == url)
        $('title').text("Home")
});
```

This is working fine for me, but I don't want to get the home page name with help of JQuery, instead, I want to get this with help of WordPress.
I need your help

Comment: Is this related to it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055009/wordpress-wp-title-blank-on-index-page

Comment: In case I use <?php bloginfo('name'); echo ' - '; is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?>
then is it giving me tagline that is provided in wp-admin => setting => tagline

Comment: all other given code also checked but not working to get page name

Comment: Then It's difficult to answer unless someone's sees your backend.

Comment: ok Thanks for yout time